# Jquery datatable datetime ascending or descending

Tags: jquery, datatables

**Jquery dataTable code**
{ 'bSortable': date-uk, 'aTargets': [2] },// this line not working for dateTime ascending or descending

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#pendingLeaveDataTable').dataTable({
            "aaSorting": [],
            "aoColumns": [`enter code here`
                    { sWidth: '20%' },
                    { sWidth: '15%' },
                    { sWidth: '15%' },
                    { sWidth: '10%' },
                    { sWidth: '10%' },
                    { sWidth: '10%' },
                    { sWidth: '10%' },
                    { sWidth: '10%' },
                    { sWidth: '10%' }, ],
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0] },
                { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0] },
                { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [6] },
                { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [7] },
                { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [8] },
                { 'bSortable': date-uk, 'aTargets': [2] },// this line not working for dateTime ascending or descending
               // { "type": "date-uk", targets: 3 }

            ]
        });
    });
```

Comment: You have to use  `{ 'sType': 'date-uk', 'aTargets': [2] }` i.e `sType` instead of `bSortable` and `date-uk` as string.

Comment: Thank for suggestion  'width 110%